# How to test Java class with Spock?

Tags: java, testing, groovy, spock

I am trying to test a class in Java with spock. I am very new to it.

```
public class VerifyUser {

    private final ServiceFacade serviceFacade;
    //here is constructor

 @RequestMapping(name = "verifyUser",
            path = "/verifyuser",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<VerifyUserResponse> verifyUser(@RequestBody VerifyUserRequest request) {

   serviceFacade.getRiskProfile(user.userId.id)
                .flatMap(ServiceFacade.RiskProfile::getAffordabilityCheck)
                        .ifPresent(ac -> {
                            String rg = ac.getRiskGroup().name();
                            VerifyUserResponse.VerifyUserResponseBuilder vur = VerifyUserResponse.builder();
                            vur.attributes.put("RiskGroup", rg);
                        });
```

Now I should test this class and see what happens if the `riskProfile` that I am getting is there.

I have started with something like this:

```
     def "should verify user"() {                                  
         given:                                                    
         def userId = "12345" 
    
     when:                                                  
     def res = mvc.perform(post(url)                        
             .content(json)                                 
             .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))      
             .andExpect(status().isOk())                    
             .andReturn()                                   
             .response                                      
                                                            
then: 1 * serviceFacade.getRiskProfile(user.userId.id) >> new ServiceFacade.RiskProfile("userId", 0, Instant.now(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty())
```

**RiskProfile.java** class looks like this:

```
    public class RiskProfile {
        public final UserId userId;
        public final long version;
        public final Instant created;
        public final Optional<Instant> lastUpdated;
        public final Optional<AffordabilityCheck> affordabilityCheck;

public RiskProfile(UserId userId, long version, Instant created, Optional<Instant> lastUpdated,
                       Optional<AffordabilityCheck> affordabilityCheck) {
        Validation.notNull(userId, "userId can not be null");
        Validation.notNull(created, "created can not be null");
        Validation.notNull(lastUpdated, "lastUpdated can not be null");
        Validation.notNull(affordabilityCheck, "affordabilityCheck can not be null");
        this.userId = userId;
        this.version = version;
        this.created = created;
        this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
        this.affordabilityCheck = affordabilityCheck;
    }

    public static RiskProfile create(UserId userId) {
        return new RiskProfile(userId, 0, Instant.now(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty());
    }

    public static RiskProfile create(UserId userId, Optional<AffordabilityCheck> affordabilityCheck) {
        return new RiskProfile(userId, 0, Instant.now(), Optional.empty(), affordabilityCheck);
```

}

When I try to run my test I get:

```
Could not find matching constructor for: com.example.ServiceFacade$RiskProfile(String, String, Optional)
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: com.example.ServiceFacade$RiskProfile(String, String, Optional)
```

Comment: What c'tor _does_ `RiskRProfile` have?

Comment: Whaat? :) you have a riskProfile class there

Comment: It's incomplete and `final` fields must be set in the c'tor.

Comment: Can you give a code example? Sorry I don’t understand what is c’tor?

Comment: constructor.  the error is complaining, that there is no c'tor with the arguments you are passing. and your code does not show the c'tor inside RiskProfile. so the most likely problem here is, that you are calling the wrong c'tor.

Comment: There is a c'tor in my class you can check a question update. Thats why I dont understend what is it about

Comment: Not only have you added the c'tor to the question, but you also have "fixed" the `new` call in your example to make it actually match.  While the error you see there would _perfectly_ match your previous attempt, this error makes no longer sense for the new code. If you still get the same error, try to clean your project. If it's still there make sure you are not actually looking at the wrong place.

Comment: Is `RiskProfile` an inner class defined inside of `com.example.ServiceFacade`?  The error message indicates that it is, but the source code suggests that it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking the following:

```
new ServiceFacade.RiskProfile("userId", 0, Instant.now(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty())
```

The first argument to the `RiskProfile` constructor needs to be a `UserId`, not a `String`.